# Use both GPS and Scan function in same channel with Junaio AR

Tags: image-processing, gps, augmented-reality, metaio, junaio

As the title says, im simply wondering if it is possible to use the GPS tracking and POI part of junaio, and att the same time use the scan functionality to scan and recognize images. Im working with a group at a project which demands that we use both functionalities, and we are at the moment stuck on trying to send 2 XML documents, causing the server to return nothing at all. I simply want to know if it is possible to use both functionalities in the same channel, and I would greatly appriciate if someone would point me in a direction which could help me solve our problems, since I've been able to find absolutley nothing on my own. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scan + GPS/compass is not possible at the moment.

However, it's possible to use GPS/compass tracking and continuous visual search at the same time. This might be the closest thing to your requirements.

You might find more information on http://helpdesk.metaio.com

Comment: thank you for the tip. We solved it by creating two channels and adding out own scan-button, taking us to the other channel which could scan. Not perfect, but worked!